# Is this set countably infinite? If so, how do I exhibit a one to one correspondence between these two sets?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I am supposed to determine whether or not the set $A\times Z^{+}$ where $A=\{2, 3\}$ is countably infinite. If so, I should  exhibit a one to one correspondence between the set of positive integers and the set in question.

Although I'm pretty sure that the set is countably infinite, I am struggling to find a one to one correspondence from the positive integers to the set since it seems to me that there are twice as many elements in the set $A\times Z^{+}$ than the set of positive integers since its cardinality is double due to the Cartesian product?

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Cantor Schroeder Bernstein Theore,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem)?  Rather than exhibiting a bijection, one can just exhibit two injections (one in each direction).  Often that is a lot easier.

Comment: So does that mean that if I map 1 -> (2,1), 2->(2,2), 3->(2,3).... and (2,1) and (3,1) ->1, (2,2) and (3,2) ->2, (2,3) and (3,3) ->3.... It would be enough to show that there is a one to one correspondence between the two sets?

Comment: I don't understand.  You have two sets, lets call them $S_1, S_2$.  Instead of exhibiting a bijection between them, it suffices to exhibit two injections, one from $S_1\to S_2$ and one from $S_2\to S_1$.

Comment: @lulu: Based on how the OP is writing, I suspect the OP has either not yet covered the CSB theorem or is not allowed to use it. Indeed, saying "... it seems to me that there are twice as many elements in ..." suggests the OP is very new to this (perhaps at school level, not university), since for instance there also seems to be twice as many integers as even integers and yet the function $f(x) = 2x$ trivially takes care of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bijection is rather obvious. E.g. for every positive integer $n$ you can define:

$F(2k-1) = (2, k)$ when $n = 2k-1$ (n is odd)

$F(2k) = (3, k)$ when $n = 2k$ (n is even)

Just prove that $F$ is a bijection (which is quite easy).

This bijection is basically a formal writing of this table:

$1 \to (2,1)$
$2 \to (3,1)$
$3 \to (2,2)$
$4 \to (3,2)$
$5 \to (2,3)$
$6 \to (3,3)$
$\dots$

*"It seems to me that there are twice as many elements in the set $A\times Z^{+}$ than the set of positive integers since its cardinality is double due to the Cartesian product"*

Well, the same intuition is probably there for the sets of **positive integers** and **even positive integers**. But there is a bijection between the two sets, hence their cardinalities are equal (one cardinality is not "twice" the other cardinality).

So whenever your intuition says that the number of elements of one set $C$ is 2 or 3 or 10 or $m$ times the number of elements of another set $B$, you should know that the two sets $B$ and $C$ are in fact of the same cardinality. It's somewhat counterintuitive at first sight but that's how it is.